# superclass storing a subclass

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know a Superclass can store an instance of a Subclass,

for example:

```
public class Subclass
{
   private int color;

   public Subclass()
   {
     color = "red";
   }
}

Superclass v = new Subclass();
```

a Superclass does not know about the methods, variables, etc in the subclass,
yet casting it, gives you access to these.

How does that work?

example:

```
Vechicle v = new Car();
Car c = (Car) v;
Consoel.WriteLine(c.color);


Output:
red
```

Comment: Every object instance has a *concrete type*. Everything else is a (compatible) "view" applied to this type, which the cast to `Car` doesn't explode - it was *always* a Car! Now, these views can play a bit of havoc (read: polymorphism doesn't act as expected) due to *non-virtual* methods and *non-virtual* operators .. but that is an entire discussion by itself!

Comment: @user2864740, your terminology is exceedingly peculiar to a C# programmer.  ("view"?  "explode"?)  What does non-virtual methods and "non-virtual operators" (!?) have to do with anything?

Comment: @LaggKing, please only post code you've compiled.  "Subclass m" is grossly illegal.

Comment: @KirkWoll Non-virtual methods change the MRO over a virtual method depending upon the "view" (or type of the *expression* of the "receiver" (or expression upon which a member is invoked (or that which is to the left of the dot))). I was pointing out that operators are non-virtual and thus suffer the same fate. "Explode" is colloquial and specifically refers to an InvalidCastException (or non-compiling program).

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as you have specified.

if color is changed in constructor of `Car` it will be different than red.

Further there is concept of [virtual methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Following is not inheritance but casting. [Inheritance msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

```
Car c = (Car) v;
```

All inherited types can be type-casted to base type, but it is not necessary.
In addition there can be user defined conversions, and conversions with helper class.
[Casting and Type Conversion - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)